# How to convert string of caps to unicode bold caps

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unicode

I want to programatically convert a string of capitals, say `"ABC"`, to a string representing the same in unicode bold caps (which start with bold A at `"\U0001d400"`)

I can do this with a character by character lookup in a tuple of the 26 unicodes:

```
x='AB'
bold_unicodes = ( '\U0001d400', '\U0001d401', ..., '\U0001d419')
result = []
for c in x:
    result.append( bold_unicodes[ ord(c)-ord('A')] )
result = ''.join(result)
```

`print(result)` yields  (yay, I can copy/paste unicodes into StackOverflow!)

But, is this really the best way? Is it the clearest?

In the interests of educating myself as to the mysteries of `bytes` and unicode, is there a way to combine an integer offset `ord(c)-ord('A')` with an integer  `0x1d400` representing the base point of 26 consecutive unicodes? Because there are a host of similar transformations for lowercase letters and numbers, into bold, italic,  and other typographies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add up the offset between the unicode blocks. In your case, the offset is `119743` (basically `ord(bold_unicodes[0])-ord('A')`), so `chr(ord(char)+119743)` returns the boldface equivalent of `char`. You could do the same for the other transformations.

One caveat: This might be obvious, but you need to make sure the input characters are in the right block so as not to get any unexpected outputs – e.g, `chr(ord('a')+119743)` returns lowercase bold ''.

Comment: Thanks. (Kicking myself, why couldn't I think of this? Some sort of ASCII-byte conditioning I guess.)